# Having problems installing therubyracer and libv8 on Rails4

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use twitter-bootswatch-rails on Rails4

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.18.10+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140303 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2650 - Linaro GCC 2014.03) ) #774 PREEMPT Wed Mar 25 13:58:34 GMT 2015
```

1. twitter-bootswatch-rails '~> 3.1.1' needs `less-rails (>= 2.3)`
2. less-rails v2.3 needs `'less', '~> 2.3.0'` and `therubyracer "~> 0.10.0"`
3. less v2.3 needs `"therubyracer", "~> 0.11.0"`
4. therubyracer v0.11.0 needs `'libv8', "~> 3.11.8"`

My Raspbian only offers

```
$ sudo apt-cache search libv8
libv8-3.8.9.20 - v8 JavaScript engine - runtime library
```

and I don't know how to have v3.11.8 libv8 installed / built from source.

I see many articles about libv8 and therubyracer problems, but not really Raspberry Pi specific.

If anyone has solved this tangling dependency problem on a Pi, I would like to know how it's done.

Comment: im having the same issue.. did you find a solution?
thanks

Comment: sadly not yet... should we ask to ordinary stackoverflow.com site and ask under as a "ruby" issue?

Comment: yes lets go ahead, post it and sent me the link so i can see/help

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I think that I am about to run into this issue, w.r.t. the Razberry Z-Wave.

Answer (score 1):

As I have already commented, I may be running into this issue shortly, as I am planning on using a [Razberry](http://razberry.z-wave.me/), a RPi dongle for use with Z-Wave home automation devices.

The partial answer to your question, and I am paraphrasing it heavily, "Is lib8 on my machine, and if not how do I get it on there?", may be found in a small, typo riddled, article from the Razberry support pages, [Will Z-Way run on my specific platform?/How to check is v8 runs on my platform?](http://razberry.z-wave.me/index.php?id=28)[sic]

> **How to check is v8 runs on my platform?**
>
> Take a copy of v8 source code (we use a specific commit) and compile
>   it. Once done, go to `v8/out/XXX.release/` and run `d8` binary. If it
>   runs, your platform is 99% supported by Z-Way. If not, read further.
>   May be some advices would help you.
>
> The snipplet below shows commands you need to execute for most common
>   cases.
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/v8/v8
> (cd v8 && git checkout 38d2d515ddeace8ea4719938f86edf316d29b576)
> make -C v8 dependencies
> LINK="g++" LD="g++" make -C v8 i18nsupport=off library=shared x64.release
> ```
>
> Change x64 to ia32 or arm or mipsel depending on your CPU. MIPS big
>   endian is not supported by v8, but we have our own port to this
>   platform tested on some CPUs. Please contact us if you need MIPS big
>   endian.
>
> If you are using cross-compilation, prior to compilation you need to
>   define CC, CXX, AR and RANLIB environment variables and CFLAGS and
>   LDFLAGS.
>
> **For the RPi**
>
> ```
> export CFLAGS = -march=armv6 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard
> export CXXFLAGS = -march=armv6 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard
> ```
>
> In this example we define specific ARM EABI and set VFP variant. You
>   need to compile `arm.release armv7=false hardfp=on snapshot=off
>   armfpu=vfp armfloatabi=hard` (these params instructs v8 to build the
>   code with hardfp EABI).
>
> For some ARMv6 processors you will need to apply our patch:
>
> ```
> patch -p0 <<END
> --- v8/src/cpu.cc       2014-02-11 13:02:05.810134031 +0400
> +++ v8/src/cpu.cc       2014-02-11 13:04:09.118128534 +0400
> @@ -379,7 +379,12 @@ CPU::CPU() : stepping_(0),
>      // an ARMv6-one. For example, the Raspberry Pi is one popular
>      // ARMv6 device that reports architecture 7.
>      if (architecture_ == 7) {
> -      char* processor = cpu_info.ExtractField("Processor");
> +      char* processor;
> +      processor = cpu_info.ExtractField("Processor");
> +      if (HasListItem(processor, "(v6l)")) {
> +        architecture_ = 6;
> +      }
> +      processor = cpu_info.ExtractField("model name");
>        if (HasListItem(processor, "(v6l)")) {
>          architecture_ = 6;
>        }
> END
> ```